# HTML table cut off on mobiles

Tags: html, css

The site I am working on has a table with wide contents. When I resize the browser it is responsive to a point but then it begins cutting off the table and does not leave a scroll bar to scroll to see the rest of the content.

Is there any CSS I have add to make it so I can scroll to see the rest of the content?

You can view the site here: http://www.launchhousing.org.au/contact-us/

[image]

Comment: please add html and css

Comment: add `overflow: scroll;` in the div tag.

Comment: It allows me to scroll

Answer (score 0):

This is a great example for responsive table ,you can use this
http://goo.gl/6079mt